# Clothing Nomenclature between US and UK

Tags: phrase-meaning

Are a waist coat and a dinner jacket the same article of clothing? Are they worn both in the US and UK?

Comment: I suggest you do a Google Images search for [waist coat](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS79dgtluaiMuQm9hPEKn8s68TUQFLTm_nsr5Jk0RBfR-Ya7jAVAxEfR-ud) and a [dinner jacket](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUJMZ55CAF9xyvDZ3SXBK68nkS7ppRThkE4WdxwBCCAXqHo_mCE5r9M8HH), and maybe also look them up on Wikipedia.

Comment: UK _waistcoat_ = US _vest_. UK _dinner jacket_ = US _tuxedo_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *[Waistcoat](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/waistcoat)* is worn in the UK as a piece of clothing without sleeves and with buttons down the front that you wear as a part of a suit.

This piece of clothing is called a *vest* in the US which is actually a piece of underwear in the UK! (Confusing, I know!)

[image]

*[Dinner jacket](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dinner-jacket)* however is a black or white jacket worn by men in the UK on very formal occasions, usually with a bow tie, and this is usually called a *tuxedo* in the US.

[image]

As mentioned in the comment above, Wikipedia provides clear explanation for both of these items.

Comment: Minor niggle: dinner jackets (or tuxedos) are for *semi*-formal occasions. The really-for-real formal attire is "white tie", which means striped trousers (the "stripes" being braid or riband hiding the seams), black or midnight blue tailcoat and white waistcoat. (If the affair is early in the day, morning dress would be appropriate.) Something to keep in mind for those Nobel-award-winning ideas; you'll need to dress up a bit.

Comment: Right @bye. I personally agree with you, but I just added the definition from the dictionary, as linked, but that's a good point to mention. (:

Answer (score 2):

Use *waistcoat* in the US and you'll be met with blank stares. As for *dinner jacket*, most Americans would assume this is synonymous with *smoking jacket* and would visualize Hugh Hefner.